# Error: Assigning to an array from an initializer list

Tags: c++, arrays, assign

I have a class such as:

```
class dialog
{
    public:
    double dReturnType[][5][3];
};
```

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
include <string>

using namespace std;
#include "dialog.h";

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    dialog People;
    People.dReturnType[0][1] = {1.2,2.3,6.6};
    return 0;
}
```

It returns:

> [Warning] extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or
>   -std=gnu11 [enabled by default]     [Error]: assigning to an array from an initializer list

I've looked it up online a bit and really couldn't find a way to get around this. I'd prefer not editing the class within it's on class file (kinda defeats the purpose). Any help?

Note: the class is in a separate project file

Answer (score 23):

**Initializer lists are just usable during initialization.**

If you want use `std::initializer_list` after initialization:

```
auto init = std::initializer_list<double>({1.2,2.3,6.6});
std::copy(init.begin(), init.end(), your_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't initialize  a extended list unless you're on c++11.

And If I was you a good habit is to use * instead of empty "[]" and allocate memory when you know the size (with new or malloc). dReturn type on your program is a pointer of matices.

And you're giving a full list to only one member of the vector.

```
People.dReturnType[0]={1.2,2.3,6.6};
```

That makes more sense.

Try to encapsulate and use/create initializer functions that will help you to do that too. C++ will put all 0 at start, but you can do a function and call:

```
dialog People("the_atributes_are_here").
```

It's a good pratice to make the dReturnType private and use functions to acess it data and insert/modify things. But that is up to you.