# Compiler issues with polymorphic classes in c++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm working on a project for a c++ class I'm taking and I can't figure out some compiler errors. My file is supposed to write a base class sprite, that has polymorphic function draw that 4 other classes inherit from. However I can't figure out these compiler issues!

> main.cpp: In function â€˜int main()â€™:
>
> main.cpp:72:47: warning: extended initializer lists only available
>   with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x  [enabled by default]
>
> main.cpp:72:47: error: assigning to an array from an initializer list
>
> main.cpp:73:23: error: expected primary-expression before â€˜)â€™
>   token
>
> main.cpp:74:21: error: expected primary-expression before â€˜)â€™
>   token
>
> main.cpp:75:22: error: expected primary-expression before â€˜)â€™
>   token
>
> main.cpp:76:20: error: expected primary-expression before â€˜)â€™
>   token
>
> main.cpp:81:13: warning: deleting array â€˜Sprite array [4]â€™
>   [enabled by default]

Here's my code!

```
#include "drawing.h"
class Sprite
{
  friend class Shadow;
  friend class Speedy;
  friend class Bashful;
  friend class Pokey;
private:
  int row;
  int col;
public:
  int getCol()
  {
    return col;
  }
  int getRow()
  {
    return row;
  }
  void setPosition(int x, int y)
  {
    row = x;
    col = y;
  }
  virtual void draw()
  {
    drawErrorMessage(row, col);
  }
};

class Shadow: public Sprite
{
public:
  virtual void draw()
  {
    drawShadow(row,col);
  }
};
class Speedy: public Sprite
{
public:
  virtual void draw()
  {
    drawSpeedy(row,col);
  }
};

class Bashful: public Sprite
{
public:
  virtual void draw()
  {
    drawBashful(row,col);
  }
};
class Pokey: public Sprite
{
public:
  virtual void draw()
  {
    drawPokey(row,col);
  }
};

int main()
{
  Sprite array[4];
  beginDrawing();
  array = {Shadow(),Speedy(),Bashful(),Pokey()};
  ((Shadow) (array[0]*)).setPosition(5,10);
 ((Speedy)(array[1]*)).setPosition(5,44);
 ((Bashful)(array[2]*)).setPosition(22,44);
 ((Pokey)(array[3]*)).setPosition(22,10);
  array[0].draw();
  array[1].draw();
  array[2].draw();
  array[3].draw();
  delete [] array;
  endDrawing();
}
```

Comment: Did you type "assigning to an array from an initializer list" in Google? Seriously, sometimes people don't realize that they can just type an error message of the compiler into Google and land on a page explaining how to solve their problem. Well if you didn't know about that trick, now you know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: Assigning to an array from an initializer list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603158/error-assigning-to-an-array-from-an-initializer-list)

Answer (score 1):

There are various problems with what you're doing:

1) You're trying to assign an initializer list to an array:

`array = {Shadow(),Speedy(),Bashful(),Pokey()};`

This is valid C++11, but not valid C++98.

2) Even if you were using C++11, this would be an unfortunate thing to do, because assigning a `Shadow` to a `Sprite` will cause slicing (the `Sprite` sub-object of the `Shadow` will be assigned, but the rest of the `Shadow` won't be). See [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c) for additional examples.

3) You're trying to `delete[]` a stack-allocated array:

```
Sprite array[4];
//...
delete [] array;
```

In general, only call `delete[]` on things you `new[]`. Simple (irrelevant) example:

```
int *arr = new int[4];
delete [] arr;
```

In the context of this question, you're allocating the *elements* of the array, not the array itself, and it's those you need to delete (using `delete` and *not* `delete[]`, since they are allocated with `new` and not `new[]`).

4) You're trying to make polymorphic calls on objects whose dynamic type is `Sprite`. Every element of your array is a `Sprite`. You probably mean to have an array of `Sprite*`, whence each element can then point to either a `Shadow`, or a `Speedy`, or ... At that point, the dynamic types of the pointed-to objects will be `Shadow`, `Speedy`, etc., and making polymorphic calls such as `array[i]->draw()` will make sense.

5) This syntax is not valid:

```
((Shadow) (array[0]*)).setPosition(5,10);
```

I'm assuming you were trying (thinking in terms of the array of pointers below) to do something like:

```
(*static_cast<Shadow*>(array[0])).setPosition(5,10);
```

In reality you almost certainly just want:

```
array[0]->setPosition(5,10);
```

---

In general, your code isn't doing quite the right thing. You probably want something more like this:

```
class Sprite
{
private:
    int col, row;
public:
    virtual ~Sprite() {}

    virtual void draw()
    {
        drawErrorMessage(row, col);
    }

    int getCol() const
    {
        return col;
    }

    int getRow() const
    {
        return row;
    }

    void setPosition(int row_, int col_)
    {
        row = row_;
        col = col_;
    }
};

class Shadow : public Sprite
{
public:
    /*virtual*/ void draw()
    {
        drawShadow(row, col);
    }
};

// etc.

int main()
{
    const int SPRITE_COUNT = 4;
    Sprite *array[SPRITE_COUNT];
    array[0] = new Shadow;
    array[0]->setPosition(5, 10);
    // etc.
    beginDrawing();
    for(int i = 0; i < spriteCount; ++i)
    {
        array[i]->draw();
        delete array[i]; // note: polymorphic deletion, hence the need for a virtual destructor
    }
    endDrawing();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But the assignment wants me to:

A main function to do the following:

Declare an array of 4 pointers to the base Sprite class.

Call beginDrawing to prepare the window for drawing.
Allocate one instance of each of the derived classes, assigning one of the array's pointers to point to each.

So how do I say that the array is 4 in length before and then add things after the call?

Comment: array can't hold polymorphism. can use vector? otherwise use an array of pointers which  point to Sprite type.

Comment: Without any mention of slicing, this is a terribly misleading answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Fair point, I'll edit it.