# How i can reset the values of my Tic Tac Toe Game

Tags: c++, tic-tac-toe

Hello i'm having problems on my program. Programming is new to me and i don't know where i will reset the values of the matrix because declaration of its values is in global.To understand more i have a comment below wherein if the game is already finish the program will ask the user if he or she wants to run the game again. Is there anyway how to fix this by adding some code or modifications to the given code. I tried to use the function goto Start; inside the if condition and in the  main function there is a Start: written. but it didnt work. Please help me thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char matrix[3][3] = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };
char player = 'X';
int rear; 


void Draw()
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "\n\n\tTic Tac Toe Game \n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout<<" \t     "; 
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void Input()
{
    int a;
    ++rear; 
    cout << "\n    Press the number of the field: ";
    cin >> a;

    if (a == 1)
        matrix[0][0] = player;
    else if (a == 2)
        matrix[0][1] = player;
    else if (a == 3)
        matrix[0][2] = player;
    else if (a == 4)
        matrix[1][0] = player;
    else if (a == 5)
        matrix[1][1] = player;
    else if (a == 6)
        matrix[1][2] = player;
    else if (a == 7)
        matrix[2][0] = player;
    else if (a == 8)
        matrix[2][1] = player;
    else if (a == 9)
        matrix[2][2] = player;
    else {
    cout<<"\n [ERROR: Invalid Range of Input is only 1-9 ]\n\n "; 
    system("pause"); 
    rear--; 
    }
}

void TogglePlayer()
{
    if (player == 'X')
        player = 'O';
    else
        player = 'X';
}
char Win()
{
    //first player
    if (matrix[0][0] == 'X' && matrix[0][1] == 'X' && matrix[0][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (matrix[1][0] == 'X' && matrix[1][1] == 'X' && matrix[1][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (matrix[2][0] == 'X' && matrix[2][1] == 'X' && matrix[2][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';

    if (matrix[0][0] == 'X' && matrix[1][0] == 'X' && matrix[2][0] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (matrix[0][1] == 'X' && matrix[1][1] == 'X' && matrix[2][1] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (matrix[0][2] == 'X' && matrix[1][2] == 'X' && matrix[2][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';

    if (matrix[0][0] == 'X' && matrix[1][1] == 'X' && matrix[2][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (matrix[2][0] == 'X' && matrix[1][1] == 'X' && matrix[0][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';

    //second player
    if (matrix[0][0] == 'O' && matrix[0][1] == 'O' && matrix[0][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (matrix[1][0] == 'O' && matrix[1][1] == 'O' && matrix[1][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (matrix[2][0] == 'O' && matrix[2][1] == 'O' && matrix[2][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';

    if (matrix[0][0] == 'O' && matrix[1][0] == 'O' && matrix[2][0] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (matrix[0][1] == 'O' && matrix[1][1] == 'O' && matrix[2][1] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (matrix[0][2] == 'O' && matrix[1][2] == 'O' && matrix[2][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';

    if (matrix[0][0] == 'O' && matrix[1][1] == 'O' && matrix[2][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (matrix[2][0] == 'O' && matrix[1][1] == 'O' && matrix[0][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';

    return '/';
}

int main()
{
    char choice; 
    Draw();
    Start: 
    while (1)
    {
        Input();
        Draw();

        if (Win() == 'X')
        {
            cout << "\n    [Message: Player 'X' Wins The Game]  ";
            break;
        }
        else if (Win() == 'O')
        {
            cout << "\n    [Message: Player 'O' Wins The Game ]" << endl;
            break;
        }
        else if(rear==9)
        {
            cout<<" Draw"<<endl; 
            break; 
        }
        TogglePlayer();
    }

    cout<<"\n\n   ";
    cout<<"Do you want to run the game again [Y/N]? ";
    cin>>choice;
    if(choice=='Y' || choice=='y')
    {
        // i don't know where i can reset the values again; 

    }
    else 
    {

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reset your game variables. I think your game variables reset values are:

```
int rear = 0;
player = 'X';
char matrix[3][3] = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };
```

While you can reset `rear` and `player` just by assigning, `matrix` will have to be "regenerated". One way to regerate `matrix` is (for more information, see [how to assign an array from an initializer list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30178879/how-to-assign-an-array-from-an-initializer-list)):

```
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = i*3+(j+1) + 48;
        }
    }
```

And finally, you have to go back to the beginning of you `main` function. You already put a `Start:` label here, so I'm assuming you were maybe trying to use `goto`? The label needs to be moved before `Draw()`. So here's your reset code:

```
if(choice=='Y' || choice=='y')
{
    // i don't know where i can restart the values again; 
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = i*3+(j+1) + 48;
        }
    }
    rear = 0;
    player = 'X';
    goto Start;
}
```

Some problems:

- You shouldn't rely on `goto`, though in this case it's still all right.
- `system("cls")` doesn't work on Linux

Comment: Sorry @tinstaafl :( I think your points are important too, so it would have been fine to keep your answer

Comment: Thanks i tried these and added to my code It worked perfectly btw what is the importance of + 48 ?

Comment: If we didn't add 48,  we would be drawing the characters with the ASCII codes 0 to 9. However, we want to print the **characters** '0' to '9', and these have the ASCII codes 48-57. (See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_set)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to create a function that does it(`void InitGame()`) and run that when needed.

On a side note:  the matrix indexes can be figured out from the position with a couple of simple algorithms `matrix[(position - 1)/3][(position - 1) % 3]`.  This could be handy in initializing the matrix as well.

Also instead of checking each line if each position equals each player, it would be simpler to just check if the values in each position equal each other, then that value represents the winner.

Comment: That's a great idea . Thanks for your comment.