# Assigning to an array from an initializer list error

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I am a beginner in c++ programming, the code below gives me the "   [Error] assigning to an array from an initializer list"
error, how to can I fix it?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>
    using namespace std;
    
    
    struct point{
        double x;
        double y;
    };

double equal(const point &u, const point &v){
    double tab[2][2];
    double dodx=(u.x+v.x);
    double dody=(u.y+v.y);
    tab = { {dodx},{dody}};
}

int main(){
    point v = {2,2};
    point u = {3,-1};
    cout<<equal(u,v);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [How can I assign an array from an initializer list?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30178912)

Comment: Even if assigning to arrays was possible, what are you trying to do? What values do you expect `tab` to contain after that assignment? Why isn't the function returning anything when it's declarad to return a `double`?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign to a c-array. You can initialize the array or use `std::array`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;
    
    
struct point{
    double x;
    double y;
};

void equal(const point &u, const point &v){
    std::array<std::array<double,2>,2> x;
    double dodx=(u.x+v.x);
    double dody=(u.y+v.y);
    x = {dodx,dody};

    double tab[2][2] = { {dodx},{dody}};
    
}

int main(){
    point v = {2,2};
    point u = {3,-1};
    equal(u,v);
    
}
```

Note that 2 `double`s is not enough initializer for a 2x2 array. The remaining elements will be initialized with `0`. Further you are not returning anything from `equal`. Your code has undefined behavior due to that (after you fix the `punkt` typo). C-arrays also cannot be returned from functions (by value), `std::array` can be returned from functions. Though you declared `equal` to return a single `double`, hence it is not clear what the function should actually do. I removed the `std::cout` and changed the return type to `void`.

Note that the extend to which beginners are tortured with c-arrays is not connected in any way to how much they are used in real code. c-arrays are difficult and error-prone and in C++ should only be used when needed. You don't need them here.

Comment: You helped me so much, thanks.